# Equivalent of forward/back buttons for unix shell (when navigating directories)?

Tags: shell, command-line, directory

I'd like to be able to type in terminal commands of forward/back especially if I went from a directory with a super-long name to home (and want to return back to the directory with the super-long name).

Comment: Can you explain some more? is `cd -` what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pushd and popd can be very useful.  For example try

```
$ pushd somedir
```

and when you are done, just do

```
$ popd
```

and you are back where you started.

The best part is you can do

```
$ pushd somedir

$ pushd anotherdir

$ pushd onemoredir
```

and then you can "step back" one at a time using popd.

Good luck!

Answer (score 18):

The command `cd -` will take you back to the previous directory.

Also look into the `pushd` and `popd` commands which can be used to basically save an ordered list of directories you were in and go back to them.

Answer (score 3):

As well as `cd -` and `pushd` and `popd` which others have mentioned, there is also `cd $OLDPWD`.   usually `cd $OL<TAB>` is enough, auto-completion at work.

When using `pushd` and `popd`, bash's `dirs` builtin can really help out, for example: `dirs -v` prints the directory stack with one entry per line, prefixed with its position number in the stack.  try `help dirs` for more.

Note that if you want change to a directory named `-`, should you have one, the above feature poses a problem.  you will need to do `cd ./-`.  better still, don't give your directories such names.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script that,by typing `cd --`, allows one to switch to one of the ten last visited directories whilst being in a particular Bash shell. Here is an example of its use:

```
lotzmana@safe$ cd work
lotzmana@safe$ cd scripts
lotzmana@safe$ pwd
/home/petarma/work/scripts
lotzmana@safe$ cd --
 0  ~/work/scripts
 1  ~/work
 2  ~
lotzmana@safe$ cd -2
lotzmana@safe$ pwd
/home/petarma
```

The script was published by Petar Marinov in the [Linux Gazette, Issue #109, December 2004](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/109/marinov.html) and also a month earlier on [geocities](http://www.geocities.com/h2428/petar/bash_acd.htm).